# What neural nets can emulate

Tags: regression, neural-networks, pca, autoencoders

I know that neural nets can emulate linear regression or logistic regression depending on the activation function used in conjuntion with a single output neuron.
Now I read to my surprise that an autoencoder in conjunction with linear activations and mean squared error (MSE) as the cost function ends up performing Principal Component Analysis.

Is there a more or less exhaustive list of popular models that can be captured by neural nets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Hand waving wildly) By the [Universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), neural networks can approximate any nonlinear function (given sufficient depth of the network).

This is what makes them so popular.

Now whether you have the appropriate data and sufficient amount of data, to estimate all of the parameters of a neural network are another story.

If you know your data adhere to a specific model, you will probably outperform a neural network. The benefits are when data deviate from this assumed model. The neural network can capture that.

And of course this is only really useful if all you care about is prediction. If you need to do inference that is much more difficult in the neural network world.